# Extract found line + subsequent line from a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to write a batch file which scans several files and looks for the string "`WARNING`".
So far I have:

```
FORFILES -m*.f08 -C"CMD /C FINDSTR /N "WARNING"  ECHO @FILE >> ListOfWARNINGS
```

Problem one: It does not print each found string in a new line.

Problem two: How can I change the code and add a `IF` statement so that it also prints the line following the line where `WARNING` was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that for getting the next line your actually going to have to loop the files & content as neither forfiles nor find support this as far as I know;

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    echo Search %%f
    for /f "usebackq eol= delims=] tokens=1*" %%l in (`find /n /v "" "%%f"`) do (
        set line=%%m
        if !printnext!==1 (
            echo.%%m >> ListOfWARNINGS
            set printnext=0
        ) else (
            if not [!line!]==[] if not !line!==!line:WARNING=X! (
                echo %%m >> ListOfWARNINGS
                set printnext=1
            ) else (
                set printnext=0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Here `if not !line!==!line:WARNING=X!` detects a match by asking if a line is equal to itself after WARNING is replaced with X.

```
C:\null>type a.txt

line 1
M O D E L S U M M A R Y
WARNING XXXXXXX
Line after warning
NUMBER OF CBAR ELEMENTS = 18655
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
WARNING ZZZZZZZ


C:\null>x.bat
Search a.txt

C:\null>type ListOfWARNINGS
WARNING XXXXXXX
Line after warning
WARNING ZZZZZZZ

C:\null>
```

Comment: Well it prints the WARNING line and the following  ,- 9 , but it also prints tons of "ECHO is OFF" and lines with a "0". Where do I have to add ">> Warnings.log  to only get these two lines. I have tried it here and there but without the desired result.

Comment: Updated above, it works fine for me in a folder with some files

Comment: Ok, thats where I had my "prints" to, but I still get a lot of "ECHO ist eingeschaltet (ON)." and "0" lines in the file. There also are some lines not containing "WARNING" such as "M O D E L   S U M M A R Y" 
"NUMBER OF CBAR     ELEMENTS =    18655" being printed to the file. I'll try to figure out why on my own, but help is appreciated.

Comment: Odd. Do those lines follow a line with WARNING?

Comment: I updated the script previously lines beginning with ; would have caused probs

Comment: No, most of them are preceded by a blank line and followed by a line only containing a "0" as the first character. Or thei are both preceded and followed by a blank line. I'll see if I can find more hints..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6894/discussion-between-lumpi-and-alex-k)

Answer (score 1):

Try  like this ,

```
@ECHO OFF
:TOP
  IF (%1)==() GOTO END
  ECHO Value is "%1" and still running...
 SHIFT
 GOTO TOP
:END
```

And See this [link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/if.php) also

Comment: Using your code fixes the linebreak problem. Any idea about how to get the line following WARNING to get printed to the outfile to?

Comment: ECHO Warrning >> ListOfWARNINGS.log

Answer (score 1):

The Alex K solution works great, and performs well as long as the files are relatively small. But if the files become big, performance can become a major problem.

I set up a test with 4 files - 3 small files less then 1Kbyte, plus 1 large ~1Mbyte file. WARNINGs were scattered through the files, including near the beginning and end of the large file.

The Alex K solution took **4.75 minutes** to complete! The problem is the entire result set of the FINDSTR within the FOR IN() must be cached, and Windows does this very inefficiently with large data sets.

Also, the solution has a potential problem in that it will corrupt any file names and/or data lines that contain `!` because of delayed expansion. This can be fixed by toggling delayed expansion on and off appropriately, also taking care to preserve variable values across ENDLOCAL border as needed.

---

It is much faster to write the results to a temporary file and then use FOR /F to read the temporary file. I modified the code to use a temp file (not shown), and the time was cut to **43 seconds.**

---

But there is still a much faster solution. The FOR loop is extremely slow at reading a file when compared to the speed of FINDSTR. Below is a solution that uses FINDSTR to search each file once for every warning, plus 2 more times. It seems like a lot of extra work, but the time to complete my test case is cut to **1 second**!

This solution also eliminates any problems due to `!` in either file names or file content.

The solution is optimized for cases where the number of WARNINGs is relatively small compared to the number of lines within the file. If the number of WARNINGs begins to approach the number of lines in the file, then it will actually become slower than the middle solution described above.

This solution also prefixes each warning with the name of the file and the line number.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set searchFiles="*.f08"
set outFile="ListOfWARNINGS"
set tempFile="%temp%\warnings%random%.txt"
set tempFile2="%temp%\warnings2_%random%.txt"
(
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /m WARNING %searchFiles% nul') do (
    findstr /n "^" "%%A" nul >%tempFile%
    echo(>>%tempFile%
    set "file=%%A"
    set "next=0"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    findstr /n WARNING "!file!" >%tempFile2%
    for /f "usebackq delims=:" %%N in (%tempFile2%) do (
      if %%N==!next! (set "current=") else set current=/c:"!file!:%%N:"
      set /a "next=%%N+1"
      findstr /bi !current! /c:"!file!:!next!:" %tempFile%
    )
    endlocal
  )
)>%outFile%
del %tempFile% 2>nul
del %tempFile2% 2>nul
```

The `/I` option in the last FINDSTR logically should not be necessary. It is there to protect against a bug where FINDSTR sometimes has problems with multiple literal search strings of different lengths.

Comment: I'll try it on monday at work on a ca 2GB large file. Thanks!!

Comment: If there aren't many WARNING lines then it shouldn't be bad. But even this solution may slow to a crawl if there are many thousands of WARNING lines in a 2GB file. If you really have to deal with files that large you might want to use VBScript, JavaScript, your compiled language of choice, or maybe a Windows port of sed.